# Android Studio: Make Tab jump to the maximum indent

Tags: tabs, android-studio, indentation

I realize this is not a programming question, but it's driving me nuts and there is no other place to ask this kind of question.

In Android Studio (1.0.2) if I press the Tab key, it jumps exactly 1 indentation level. Even if I am in the middle of some heavily nested code, and I have to press Tab a bazilion times to arrive at the maximum indentation level, where it should have put the cursor in the first place.

Both Eclipse and Xcode jump to the max indent level if I press Tab, and that works way better for me.

**How can we set the Tab key to jump to the maximum indent every time?**

Answer (score -1):

I'm running the same version (Mac), and was looking for the same thing.

- Go to Android Studio Settings ---> Keymap
- Find the entry for "Emacs tab" and assign a key.

This option does not have a key assigned by default, so you need to create one yourself.

If you really like the way Emacs works for tabs (I do), you can assign the `tab key` to this, and will be the default.

Working fine here now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. For one, it makes AS lag in the moment I press the assigned key, second it goes half the way to the end and than stops and refuses to go further by pressing the shortcut key.

Comment: not sure why it does not got to all the way... here is working fine for that purpose. Regarding adding more tabs, seems to be way that this really should work. By the name, this is the emacs tab, and this is how emacs works. But anyway, your question was how to make it go to the max ident, and this solution solves that.